# Block device writes

Tags: block-device

I am trying to understand how block device writes work. My understanding is all writes need to be sector aligned. So if the sector size 512 bytes then all writes are of size 512 bytes. Now let us say I create a file and start writing sequentially into it (no buffering on the application side). Now suppose I start by writing 16 bytes at offset zero of the file. How does this translate into a write at the block level? Is it buffered till I have written a "sector size" amount of data and then pushed out to disk? If fsync is called are the remaining bytes padded and then written out? Is the understanding correct or am I way off.

The follow up question was the following. If I have a file say of size 64K. Let us say I perform a random write of 16 bytes at offset 64. Then the appropriate sector of 512 bytes is read the 16 bytes are written into the buffer at offset 64 and then the 512 bytes written out to disk. Is the understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's called Read-Modify-Write: you must first read the sector, change the bytes requested, and write it back.
Only in the case of full-sector writes can you ignore this step.

I don't know about Linux, but in Windows' case, it normally performs buffering as you mentioned until the buffer is full (the buffer is likely a multiple of the sector size), or it avoids buffering entirely and throws an exception if the write is unaligned or not a full sector, depending on whether or not you requested buffering.